# "Error: error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing "

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

please I get this errror when instantiating a chaincode on one of the peers

"Error: error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
"

Attached below are pictures of the orderer and peer logs [image: Orderer0 logs]

[image: Peer0 logs]

I use this code for instantiation `peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer0.andyke.com:7050 --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA -C onetwochannel -n tester -v 2.0 -c '{"Args":["init"]}' -P "AND ('BankoneMSP.peer','BanktwoMSP.peer')"`

I have installed the chaincode tester on each peers in the two organisations that make up the onetwochannel channel

Comment: Can you give me a sample command for it? The one that uses tls

Comment: that's exactly the same command I am making use of. I have already installed the chaincode on all the peers from the orgs that are members of the channel